# "Don't" or "not to" or "to not"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, difference

Why is this sentence used "not to"? Is this some other meaning?

What will be the difference if replaced by another and what will it mean?

> Tell him ***not to***(***Don't***/***to not***) wait for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of them carry the same meaning. *Not to* and *to not* would be more natural, *don't* would be more commonly used in direct speech:

> "Don't tell me," he said to her.